# Devise + CanCan just prevent other users from editing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

How would you prevent other users from editing a object, say a profile object that does - not - belong to themselves?

Most online examples are complexes with multiple user roles, i haven't been able to get this working, must be simple though:

```
  def initialize(user)

      can :update, Profile do |profile|
        profile.try(:user) == current_user
      end

  end
```

And inside my ProfilesController#edit

```
authorize! :update, @profile
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First question is, have you made your roles for the `User`?

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, # regular devise stuff
  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users

  ROLES = %w[admin default banned]

  private

  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I have 3 different roles here and when a new user is created they are always `default` users. Now with CanCan set up, lets say you wanted to have the `admin` be able to do everything, the `default` users be able to do everything with their own profiles, `banned` users cannot do anything and guest users be able to see profiles:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  # Remember that CanCan is for a resource, meaning it must have a class(model).

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == "default"
      can :manage, Profile, :user_id => user.id
    elsif user.role == "banned"
      cannot :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Profile # guest user
    end
  end
end
```

So that's how you let users edit only their own profiles and nobody elses.

---

**Some other handy notes:** Make sure you have a `user_id` column in your `Profile` table. Also if you may need to let guess users see profiles like this:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :show
    load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

They won't be able to use any other action and CanCan still checks authentication on everything else except `show`.

Good luck!

---

UPDATE: **Making :role attribute for Users**

What I did was run a migration that would add the `role` column to the Devise `users` table:

```
rails generate migration add_role_to_users role:string
```

And then `rake db:migrate`. The new migration file should look like this and also check your **db/schema.rb** file to make sure its apart of the users table correctly. If it isn't then `rake db:drop`, then `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate` again.

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :role, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :role
  end
end
```

This is how you successfully make the `user.role` work.

Note: Make sure you leave the line: `can :manage, Profile, :user_id => user.id` as is with no changes. It should work after adding the `role` column to `user`.

IMPORTANT! If you use Rails 3, DO **NOT** MAKE `role` `attr_accessible` or everyone can edit their roles! Rails 4 uses [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) by default and is not affected by this issue as you can choose the allowed parameters.

Comment: Thx for the info, I had some old info since cancan was upgraded, causing some issues, still haven't got this - looks simple - thing fixed. I copied the code from your example above. the user.role part isn't totally clear to me, where does the user.role come from? a column in the user table? Still getting a "You are not authorized to access this page." Since I'm using devise current_user should return the current logged in user ID. Maybe "        can :manage, Profile, :user_id => user.id" is the problem, I've tried changing this to current_user instead restarted app with same result however.

Comment: Even setting in user model       self.role = "admin" hardcoded and restarting app does not let me edit any profile or view them, very strange I'm not seeing what I miss here, any suggestions would be welcome :) thx

Comment: @Rubytastic Check out the edit and if you need more information you can go here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization but its basically the same thing.

Comment: I fixed it but totally forgot to flag this as winning answer, great answer and writeup. Seemed I had some non default logic in controller that messed things up, hence the confusement on my part why it dident work even following the docs. probably a good one for future folks having problems with it

Comment: @Rubytastic Cool, glad everything is working for you. Good luck with your application.

Answer (score 4):

Give something like this a try....

```
can :update, Profile, :user_id => user.id
```

Comment: That gives the same : You are not authorized to access this page.

Comment: Just checking, but does the Profile have a user_id column (belongs_to :user) set up in the database? I just checked my project (which does exactly what you're trying to do), I have it set up as 'can [:edit, :update], User, :id => user.id', so you may have to play around with the above values to properly adapt it to however yours is set up.

Comment: Also, one oversight on my part: difference in your set up versus mine is that I'm editing the user directly, you are editing a profile which belongs to a user, I take it? No promises as I'm just throwing this out of my head, but give something like this a shot: 'can :update, Profile, :user => { :id => user.id }'

Comment: Still haven't fount a solution anyone using devise with cancan and know the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Seems like the above code examples where correct. After reading all of the docs of cancan rtfm ;p I found out about the role column you need to add.

Because of the way I have my profile update action organized it seems CanCan does not work! I solved like below:

```
  def edit

    @profile = Profile.find params[:id]
    what = params[:what]

    if can? :update, @profile
      if ["basics", "location", "details", "photos", "interests"].member?(what)
        render :action => "edit_#{what}"
      else
        render :action => "edit_basics"
      end
    else
      raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new("Not authorized!", :update, Profile)
    end
  end
```

Maybe not the cleanest way but the only way to get it to work. Any suggestions on improvements are welcome, I did have the

```
  load_and_authorize_resource
```

Inside profiles controller though! Perhaps a bug