# In Rails 4 I want to create a movie and then change the permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, create a little movie reviews app like IMDB.

I am assuming it is something like this

```
# app/models/User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :movies, through: :reviews
end


# app/models/Movie.rb
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
end


class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end


# app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
class Reviews Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :reviews]
```

My question is, how would I do it that a User would create a Movie, and then change the permissions after create that wouldn’t allow anyone to change it, including the User who created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following post to allow only the users who created the objects can change it:

[devise-cancan-just-prevent-other-users-from-editing-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332035/devise-cancan-just-prevent-other-users-from-editing-objects).

This uses **canCan** to provide role based permissions explained in detail.

Then modify your code for the Movie accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need create some perrmission system, i.e. using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Then in `before_filter` you will check if the current user has perrmision to perform given action.